# Unmanaged C++ BT/LE on RP/Win and pairing programmatically, possible?

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy, unmanaged, iot

I have an unmanaged c++ application that I'd like to port to Windows Raspberry Pi. It was originally developed on an embedded platform but was written to be highly portable using a pseudo-HAL to wall off the 10-15% of platform specific code. So it easily ports to / runs on windows desktop as well with zero changes to the common ~85%. It's currently written to support ANT+ sensors though we would like to add (or may possibly replace ANT with) BT/LE support. That said from looking at a ton of docs and examples online it's not super clear if it's even possible without a rewrite. If it comes to that though we would probably target linux instead. Anyway, three questions -

(1) Is it even possible?

(2) If so what is the best approach (i.e. what API's should I be looking at, and how should I wrap them for unmanaged use)?

(3) Is there a way to programatically pair the RP with our target sensors on the fly, i.e. scan for available sensors and pair by a predefined type and possibly ID (and again if so what API's should I look at)?

I hate to ask such open ended questions but it's just not clear from the examples I've been looking at online since everything is pretty much UWP oriented and I'm not really familiar with any of that at all. Just looking to get a yes/no on feasibility and a point in the right direction if so. Thanks for any input, chris

Answer (score 0):

Figured I'd follow up on this for anyone else that goes down the same path... here's what I found  eventually -

1) Is it even possible... Yes it's possible. I was able to get it working though due to the lack of documentation/examples what I came up with may not be the optimum solution. It does seem solid though from the limited testing I've done.

2) If so what is the best approach... Again, not sure this is the best approach but the very short answer is that do make it work you need to use WRL via COM. All the interfaces needed for both scanning and pairing are found in "windows.devices.enumeration.h" and you'll want to use the following namespaces - ABI::Windows::Foundation; Microsoft::WRL; Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers; ABI::Windows::Devices::Enumeration. Since many of the objects/interfaces you'll need are not documented at all (e.g. "IDeviceInformationStatics2") you'll need to use QueryInterface a good bit to find out what's available.

3) Is there a way to programatically pair... Yes, as noted above it's possible. It took me a few weeks to pick through it all and get it working but looking at the various related examples online and piecing it together it seems to work. One thing that I was concerned about was passing BLE pin codes where needed without a UI. That works too though again not really documented (see "AcceptWithPin")....